# Avoid random adding of xmlns attribute

Tags: sax, xml-namespaces

I have two copies of a Java project.

After running this method:

```
private void editArtifactWSDL() {
    try {
        File outputfile = new File(
        "C:\\WorkSpace\\CMU\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\bpelfiles\\process\\Artifacts.wsdl");

        File skeletonFile = new File(
        "C:\\WorkSpace\\CMU\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\bpelfiles\\SkeletonArtifacts.wsdl");

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(skeletonFile);

        Element definitionsElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

        // xmlns attributes
        editDefinitionsElementToArtifact(doc, definitionsElement);

        // partnerLinkType elements
        appendPartnerLinkTypeElementsToArtifact(doc, definitionsElement);

        // import elements
        appendImportElementsToArtifact(doc, definitionsElement);

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
        .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outputfile);

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(
        "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("Artifact.wsdl saved!");

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sxe) {
        sxe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in one of the projects i get a "clean" `Artifacts.wsdl`. In the other project I get  `xmlns=""` added to some elements.

The SkeletonArtifacts.wsdl is exacly the same (compared on http://www.diffnow.com/)

So what can be the reason for this random behavior and do I get rid of the the xmlns attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I have made my `DocumentBuilder` NameSpaceAware by making the `DocumentFactory` NameSpaceAware as well with the following code:

```
docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

the `xmlns=""` attributes have now dissapeared.

I still don't understand why this happens randomly. The other project does not add the `xmlns=""` even though its `DocumentBuilder` is NOT NameSpaceAware.

Any explanation on this is still wellcome.

EDIT:

After  setting the NameSpaceAware I realized the Elements added after parsig still have the `xmlns=""`.

I think there was a conflict for `Transfomer` class from JRE7 and SAXON jars added to integrate ODE in the project.